# how to create a vertical content Slider in android Activity

Tags: android

**I want to create a vertical slider like as shown in image**
[slider image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsqbO.png)

Comment: Do you want to hear "Good luck"? Please, Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an example do this:

- get the .apk for that application
- decompile it
- try to understand how they've done it from the source code